# Using `null as string | null` in Typescript gives `Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I am following a React Toolkit tutorial that uses Typescript, and came across the use of

```
initialState: null as string | null,
```

in the [example code provided](https://github.com/angle943/redux-toolkit-comparison/blob/finished-version/src/redux-toolkit.ts#L78) and explained at [this part of the video](https://youtu.be/9lCmbth63k0?t=7507):

```
const selectedTodoSlice = createSlice({
  name: "selectedTodo",
  initialState: null as string | null,
  reducers: {
    select: (state, { payload }: PayloadAction<{ id: string }>) => payload.id
  }
});
```

However, when I run my code on my system containing the same block, the JS console gives the error

```
index.js:1 src/redux-toolkit.ts
  Line 76:22:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

  74 | const selectedTodoSlice = createSlice({
  75 |   name: "selectedTodo",
> 76 |   initialState: null as string | null,
     |                      ^
  77 |   reducers: {
  78 |     select: (state, { payload }: PayloadAction<{ id: string }>) => payload.id,
  79 |   },
```

Why is it giving an error, and how can we fix this?

---

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "rtk",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.6.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.1.9",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.23",
    "@types/node": "^15.12.4",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.11",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.8",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.16",
    "@types/redux-logger": "^3.0.8",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.2",
    "prettier": "^2.3.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "redux": "^4.1.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.4",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

---

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried just doing `initialState: null as string`?

Comment: @j-petty Yup, same error message

Comment: Okay and just to confirm the TypeScript file you are editing is a .ts file, rather than .js? Otherwise it may be running vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: @j-petty Correct, the file is named `redux-toolkit.ts`

Comment: Can you please share your tsconfig?

Comment: @j-petty Sure, updated the questoin with the `tsconfig.json`

Comment: The error indicates that the code is not running in a Typescript environment. Are you sure you are running your code using a typescript compiler? What is the command you are using to execute the files?

Comment: @AmirSaleem I am starting the app using the command `yarn start`

Comment: what is the `start` script in your `package.json?`

Comment: @AmirSaleem It's `"start": "react-scripts start"`

Comment: so it is running a JS code not typescript. You need to use a typescript compiler `tsc` command

Comment: @AmirSaleem I have another React typescript project that can run successfully using `"react-scripts start"`. I think Typescript compiler is being used also because there's a few uses of the Typescript syntax in the same file as the one in question but theres no error with those Typescript syntax

Comment: Such as `Todo[]` at https://github.com/angle943/redux-toolkit-comparison/blob/finished-version/src/redux-toolkit.ts#L13

Answer (score 1):

This code came straight from an example, so it’s not the code that’s the problem.  It’s an inability of your start script to parse Typescript.

React-scripts [can handle TypeScript](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/) without any additional configuration (since version 2.1.0).

#### it’s eslint

Your error doesn’t mention eslint at all, but I’m pretty sure it’s eslint which is the problem here.  “react-scripts start” calls eslint to log warnings to the console.  I’m seeing that you have some eslint packages in your package.json but not @typescript-eslint/parser.  I suggest installing both @typescript-eslint/parser and @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin and setting the parser option of your eslint config to use @typescript-eslint/parser, [as explained here](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/HEAD/docs/getting-started/linting/README.md).